# Search function - logic in the wrong place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing a basic search function on an app that was set up by someone else. There are 3 tables `Booking`, `Room` and `Host` and the search feature needs to ask the user for 3 fields: `start_date`, `end_date` and `number_of_guests`.

The search needs to return a list of hosts which have rooms available for that period (start_date/end_date params) and that number of guests in the same room, showing which rooms are available for that host for that time period and if any of the rooms already have guests booked into them.

The search also needed to work out which hosts were available based on their existing bookings (listed in the `Bookings` table) and it needed to show all the hosts with rooms available, even if the rooms are partially booked.

My current solution looks like this. In `app/views/search/new.html.erb`:

```
<div class="row search-area">
  <%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="small-12 medium-1 large-1 columns search-field">
    <%= label_tag "From", nil, class: "right inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns search-field">
    <%= text_field_tag(:start_date, params[:start_date]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-1 large-1 columns search-field">
    <%= label_tag "To", nil, class: "right inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns search-field">
    <%= text_field_tag(:end_date, params[:end_date]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-1 large-1 columns search-field">
    <%= label_tag "Guests", nil, class: "right inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns search-field">
    <%= number_field(:number_of_guests, params[:number_of_guests], in: 1.0..20.0, step: 1.0) %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-3 large-3 columns">
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, :class => "button" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In `search_controller.rb`:

```
  def index
    @start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
    @end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])
    @guests = (params[:number_of_guests]).first.to_i
    @space = 0

    @bookings = Booking.all
    @hosts = [] # this will store available hosts

    # get all hosts for specified time period
    @bookings.each { |b| @hosts.push(b.room.host) if ((b.start_date >= @start_date &&
      b.start_date <= @end_date) || (b.end_date >= @start_date &&
      b.end_date <= @end_date)) }

    @hosts = @hosts.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
```

And in `app/views/search/index.html.erb`:

```
<div>
<% @hosts.each do |host| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% if host.rooms.any? { |room| room.bookings.empty? } %>
      <!-- if a host has rooms without bookings then they are definitely going to have free rooms -->
      <div class="small-3 medium-4 large-4 columns">
        <%= image_tag host.picture_url %>
      </div>
      <div class="small-9 medium-8 large-8 columns">
        <p>Host #<%= host.id %>: <%= host.name %></p>
        <p><%= host.address %></p>
        <% host.rooms.each do |room| %>
          <!-- display information on free rooms -->
          <% if room.bookings.empty? %>
            <p>room #<%= room.id %> is available (0 booked, <%= room.capacity %> free out of <%= room.capacity %>)</p>
          <% else %>
            <!-- for the rooms with bookings - check if rooms are fully booked first -->
            <% unless ((room.capacity - room.bookings.first.number_of_guests) == 0) %>
              <% total_booked = room.bookings.first.number_of_guests %>
              <% space = room.capacity - total_booked %>
              <p>room #<%= room.id %> is available (<%= total_booked %> booked, <%= space %> free out of <%= room.capacity %>)</p>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
    <!-- if all the rooms belonging to a host are booked - check if all the rooms are fully booked -->
      <% if !(host.rooms.all? { |room| (room.capacity - room.bookings.first.number_of_guests) == 0 }) %>
        <!-- If all the rooms are fully booked there is nothing to display so there is no else block. Check the rooms individually for availability -->
        <div class="small-3 medium-4 large-4 columns">
          <%= image_tag host.picture_url %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 medium-8 large-4 columns">
          <p>Host #<%= host.id %>: <%= host.name %></p>
          <p><%= host.address %></p>
          <% host.rooms.each do |room| %>
            <% unless ((room.capacity - room.bookings.first.number_of_guests) == 0) %>
              <% total_booked = room.bookings.first.number_of_guests %>
              <% space = room.capacity - total_booked %>
              <p>room #<%= room.id %> is available (<%= total_booked %> booked, <%= space %> free out of <%= room.capacity %>)</p>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I realise there are a lot of issues with this solution as it is so I'm asking if anyone can point me in the right direction with regards the steps I need to take to make this code adhere to best practices and more performant/efficient. Specifically:

1. I know the logic for filtering the hosts for available rooms shouldn't be in the view file but I'm unsure of how to move it to the controller or if that is even the right place for it. I'm having breaking down the logic for putting this code somewhere else.
2. I don't have a search model because it's my understanding that models are associated with database tables and the search feature isn't. Am I wrong in thinking this?
3. There's a lot of repetition in the view, I'm hoping that's cleared up when I've finally figured out where the logic filtering rooms/hosts should go but if it isn't any tips for DRYing up the view file?
4. I know that when I'm calculating the space available in each room - I only check the first booking for that room. At the moment each room only has 1 booking but I know it won't stay this way and realistically I should check all the bookings for the room for that time period. I haven't done this because it ties in with my confusion as to how to further filter hosts after I've retrieved those available based on the start/end_date params.

Any help figuring out the steps towards making this more rails/ruby-ist and more performant would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the search logic in the controller isn't a good idea because you might want to re-use that logic in another controller (API for example) in future so I suggest that you create a `services` folder inside your app directory `app/services` where you'll have a `SearchService` class with a `search` function that takes query and filter parameters and returns the results.

For the view I suggest that you move all the logic to it's respective models, for example in the `Host` model add a function that checks whether all the rooms are booked or not `host.are_all_rooms_booked?` and in the `Room` model add a `total_bookings` function and so on.

This way you'll have a simpler view and all the logic will be in either the models or a service so it is re-usable from other parts in the application.

Comment: Thanks for the tips about putting logic in individual models, that seems to be really clearing things up. As for the services folder, does that do in the root directory of my app? And can I then link that search feature to search#index - I was specifically asked to implement that action.

Comment: The `services` directory will be inside your `app` directory `app/services` and you can use the `SearchService` in your `SearchController#index` action `@results = SearchService.search(params[:query], params[:filter])`

Comment: Glad I helped, if this answers your question please accept my answer